# Remote Management Wizard Not Showing On First Use

Tags: mdm

I have a new MBP bought through Apple Business and registered in Apple Business Manager. ABM is integrated with Azure Intune. On first use the Remote Management interface popped up but failed to obtain automatic configuration settings. I tried a few times, in the end turned the machine off.

I rang Apple and they said reinstall macOS. I did so, and since then I've never had the Remote Management interface pop up. I just get the normal consumer experience which is useless to me.

Apple believe there's an issue with the Intune configuration. I'm not convinced as I followed the Intune documentation for setting this up and everything checks out. Syncs are occurring, the device is visible as pending enrollment, good signals on both Intune and ABM side.

I think the mac is stuck in consumer mode now and doesn't know to check for MDM settings?

I've tried deleting the Macintosh HD - Data volume, erasing the Macintosh HD volume and reinstalling. No change. If I continue the consumer setup experience I just get a normal, non-managed mac.

Any ideas on:

A - Is it stuck in consumer mode?

B - Should I try anything on the Intune side? I'm contemplating deleting all Device Configuration policies to simplify things so only the Enrollment program token profile is left.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reset the device so the Remote Management wizard comes back up on device setup. I believe the steps that fixed it were:

1. Turn off mac
2. Unassign device from MDM in ABM
3. Re-assign device to MDM in ABM
4. Assign profile again in Intune
5. Sync devices in Intune
6. Reinstall macOS via Delete Macintosh HD - Data volume delete method

Though now I'm left with an unusual credential prompt. I have no idea what identity it expects. ABM is federated with Azure AD and as this isn't an Office 365 login screen that rules out corporate credentials. It's not an ABM credential either. Hrm!

[image]